Book about a boy and girl in a city with evil gods
I can't remember this book title but I really want to reread it. It has a blue and gold cover and was published in or around 2019. It has a pretty short title from what I remember.
It is about a boy and a girl. And they have evil gods in the city that they are in. The girl is the daughter of one of the gods living with her sisters. In the end, the boy ends up being one of the lost sons of one of the gods.
The book starts out with the boy leaving his city in search of the new one, but once he gets there it's not like he thought it would be.
The boy and the girl can also communicate through dreams.
